# Joomla, how to display category name in module latest

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I've been trying to display the category name after the contents of the 'Latest' module in Joomla.

I've made the query in phpMyAdmin and it works. But when I try to use this in the php module template page the page stops at the point the php should start.

```
$db = &JFactory::getDBO(); 
$id = JRequest::getString('id'); 
$db->setQuery("SELECT `title` FROM `#__categories` WHERE `id` = " .$item->catid); 
$category = $db->loadResult();
echo $category;
```

When I replace $item->catid with a fixed number, it works like it does in phpMyAdmin. Can anyone tell me where I go wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I have submitted an answer Hope that helps you.

Comment: What I'm looking for is to have, at the end of the latest list, a sentence "Click here for more news on (category name)"

Comment: But that was not mentioned anywhere in your question. You can always open a new question and send me the link. i will be glad to help you.

Comment: I am not able to understand your question. There will be suppose 5 items all will have different ids and names, which one you want at the end of list? or you have just one category?

Comment: Has `$item` already been defined in the file prior to where it is called?

Answer (score 0):

$item is already having the category title so no need to get it through a db query. You can simply do this in your tmpl file. You can get the category using `$item->category_title`

```
<ul class="latestnews<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="name">
                <?php echo $item->title; ?>-
                <b><?php echo $item->category_title; ?></b>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE:**
if you want to display as you asked in comments then you need to do this

```
<ul class="latestnews<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php foreach ($list as $item) :  ?>
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="name">
                <?php echo $item->title; ?>       
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<b><a href="<?php JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=$item->category_title&id=$item->catid"); ?>">Click here for more news on ("<?php echo $item->category_title; ?>")</a></b>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, Although this gives me a better insight I'm not quite there yet. 
Your solution gives me an article list extended with the category name.

What I'm looking for is to have, at the end of the list, a sentence "Click here for more news on (category name)"

Do you know a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: @redmac21 This will be an incorrect answer to the original question you asked. I have answered what you had asked. So i suggest you to ask a new question with the required details and send me the link. I can help you on that.

Comment: @redmac21 Just check if this helps.